# modal form not submitting

Tags: html

The problem is that when i click on the button nothing happens at all which it should be at least to me.

I don't need a direct answer. Just a hint, or a pointer of what can be going on.

Here is part of the code for the modal form

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <form Method="POST" id="Signin-Form" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
            <input name="txt_uname" id="txt" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter User Name" />
            </div>                     
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
            <input name="txt_umail" id="email" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Email" required data-parsley-type="email"  />
            </div>                     
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
            <input name="txt_upass" id="pass1" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Password" required data-parsley-length="[6, 10]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" />
            </div>                       
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
            <input name="txt_upass2" id="pass2" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" required data-parsley-length="[6, 10]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" />
            </div>                      
        </div>



          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file">CREATE ACCOUNT!</i></button>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **action attribute** to the form to be able to send the form-data when the form is submitted.

Sample code below

```
<form action="submittedpage.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

After you click submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file named "submittedpage.php". The form data is sent with the HTTP POST method.

To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables. The "submittedpage.php" see the code below:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

You can see this link for more info in form handling.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. It's a registration modal form. When the user clicks on the button after filling out the form it's supposed to submit the data to the database. How ever nothing happens.

Comment: what database are you using and do you use php as your backend?

Comment: Using wamp on localhost. using php version 5.6.31 with phpmyadmin ( mysql version is on 5.7.19)

Comment: it actually ended up being an issue with javascript validation. after hours of sifting and combing through every bit of mark up I found what the issue was.I know it's a bit late now I've been busy and haven't found the time to update you. I believe I upvoted anyway since it was one part of the problem. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: I see no worries.